# How can I plot a function of imported data that ends up nested in lists four deep?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data, visualization

I imported a file of data from a model that I am running for my research.  It produces the following output in *Mathematica*:

```
{{{0., 0.000165181, 0.000356766, 0.000580454, 0.000840913, 0.00114424,
   0.00149746, 0.00190878, 0.0023877, 0.00294529, 0.00359441, 
   0.00435001, 0.00522944, 0.00625283, 0.00744356, 0.00882869, 
   0.0104396, 0.0123126, 0.0144895, 0.0170189, 0.0199566, 0.0233666, 
   0.0273229, 0.0319097, 0.0372236, 0.0433745, 0.050487, 0.0587019, 
   0.0681775, 0.0790907, 0.091638, 0.106036, 0.12252, 0.141345, 
   0.162785, 0.187125, 0.214662, 0.245696, 0.280526, 0.319439, 0.3627,
    0.410546, 0.463171, 0.520721, 0.583283, 0.65088, 0.723468, 
   0.800935, 0.883108, 0.96975, 1.06058, 1.15526, 1.25345, 1.35477, 
   1.45883, 1.56524, 1.67363, 1.78363, 1.8949, 2.00712, 2.11999, 
   2.23324, 2.34662, 2.45991, 2.57292, 2.68547, 2.79741, 2.90861, 
   3.01895, 3.12833, 3.23668, 3.34391, 3.44996, 3.5548, 3.65837, 
   3.76064, 3.86159, 3.96119, 4.05943, 4.1563, 4.25179, 4.3459, 
   4.43864, 4.52999, 4.61997, 4.70858, 4.79584, 4.88175, 4.96632, 
   5.04956, 5.1315, 5.21213, 5.29149, 5.36957, 5.4464, 5.52199, 
   5.59637, 5.66953, 5.74151, 5.81231, 5.88196, 5.95047, 6.01786, 
   6.08414, 6.14933, 6.21345, 6.27651, 6.33853, 6.39952, 6.4595, 
   6.5185, 6.57651, 6.63356, 6.68966, 6.74483, 6.79909, 6.85244, 
   6.9049, 6.95649, 7.00722, 7.05711, 7.10616, 7.1544, 7.20182, 
   7.24846, 7.29432, 7.33941, 7.38375, 7.42735, 7.47022, 7.51237, 
   7.55381, 7.59457, 7.63464, 7.67404, 7.71277, 7.75087, 7.78832, 
   7.82515, 7.86135, 7.89696, 7.93196, 7.96638, 8.00022, 8.0335, 
   8.06621, 8.09838, 8.13001, 8.16111, 8.19168, 8.22175, 8.25131, 
   8.28037, 8.30895, 8.33704, 8.36467, 8.39183, 8.41853, 8.44479, 
   8.47061, 8.49599, 8.52095, 8.54549, 8.56961, 8.59333, 8.61666, 
   8.63959, 8.66213, 8.6843, 8.7061, 8.72753, 8.7486, 8.76931, 
   8.78968, 8.80971, 8.82939, 8.84875, 8.86779, 8.8865, 8.9049, 
   8.92299, 8.94078, 8.95827, 8.97546, 8.99236, 9.00899, 9.02533, 
   9.0414, 9.05719, 9.07273, 9.088, 9.10301, 9.11777, 9.13229, 
   9.14656, 9.16059, 9.17438, 9.18795, 9.20128, 9.21439, 9.22728, 
   9.23996, 9.25242, 9.26467, 9.27672, 9.28856, 9.30021, 9.31165, 
   9.32291, 9.33398, 9.34486, 9.35556, 9.36608, 9.37642, 9.38659, 
   9.39658, 9.40641, 9.41608, 9.42558, 9.43492, 9.4441, 9.45314, 
   9.46201, 9.47074, 9.47933, 9.48777, 9.49606, 9.50422, 9.51224, 
   9.52012, 9.52788, 9.5355, 9.54299, 9.55036, 9.55761, 9.56473, 
   9.57173, 9.57862, 9.58539, 9.59204, 9.59859, 9.60502, 9.61135, 
   9.61757, 9.62368, 9.6297, 9.63561, 9.64142, 9.64713, 9.65275, 
   9.65827, 9.6637, 9.66904, 9.67429, 9.67946, 9.68453, 9.68952, 
   9.69443, 9.69925, 9.70399, 9.70865, 9.71324, 9.71774, 9.72217, 
   9.72653, 9.73081, 9.73503, 9.73917, 9.74324, 9.74724, 9.75118, 
   9.75504, 9.75885, 9.76259, 9.76627, 9.76988, 9.77344, 9.77693, 
   9.78037, 9.78375, 9.78707, 9.79033, 9.79354, 9.7967, 9.7998, 
   9.80286, 9.80586, 9.80881, 9.81171, 9.81456, 9.81736, 9.82012, 
   9.82283, 9.82549, 9.82811, 9.83069, 9.83322, 9.83571, 9.83816, 
   9.84057, 9.84293, 9.84526, 9.84755, 9.8498, 9.85201, 9.85418, 
   9.85632, 9.85842, 9.86049, 9.86252, 9.86452, 9.86648, 9.86841, 
   9.87031, 9.87218, 9.87401, 9.87581, 9.87759, 9.87933, 9.88105, 
   9.88273, 9.88439, 9.88602, 9.88762, 9.8892, 9.89075, 9.89227, 
   9.89377, 9.89524, 9.89669, 9.89811, 9.89951, 9.90088, 9.90224, 
   9.90357, 9.90487, 9.90616, 9.90742, 9.90867, 9.90989, 9.91109, 
   9.91227, 9.91343, 9.91457, 9.91569, 9.9168, 9.91788, 9.91895, 9.92,
    9.92103, 9.92204, 9.92304, 9.92402, 9.92498, 9.92593, 9.92686, 
   9.92778, 9.92868, 9.92956, 9.93043, 9.93129, 9.93213, 9.93296, 
   9.93377, 9.93457, 9.93536, 9.93613, 9.93689, 9.93764, 9.93837, 
   9.93909, 9.9398, 9.9405, 9.94119, 9.94186, 9.94253, 9.94318, 
   9.94382, 9.94445, 9.94507, 9.94568, 9.94628, 9.94687, 9.94745, 
   9.94802, 9.94858, 9.94913, 9.94967, 9.9502, 9.95072, 9.95124, 
   9.95175, 9.95224, 9.95273, 9.95321, 9.95368, 9.95415, 9.95461, 
   9.95506, 9.9555, 9.95593, 9.95636, 9.95678, 9.95719, 9.9576, 9.958,
    9.95839, 9.95877, 9.95915, 9.95953, 9.95989, 9.96025, 9.96061, 
   9.96096, 9.9613, 9.96164, 9.96197, 9.96229, 9.96261, 9.96293, 
   9.96324, 9.96354, 9.96384, 9.96413, 9.96442, 9.96471, 9.96499, 
   9.96526, 9.96553, 9.9658, 9.96606, 9.96631, 9.96657, 9.96682, 
   9.96706, 9.9673, 9.96753, 9.96777, 9.96799, 9.96822, 9.96844, 
   9.96866, 9.96887, 9.96908, 9.96928, 9.96949, 9.96969, 9.96988, 
   9.97007, 9.97026, 9.97045, 9.97063, 9.97081, 9.97099, 9.97116, 
   9.97133, 9.9715, 9.97167, 9.97183, 9.97199, 9.97215, 9.9723, 
   9.97245, 9.9726, 9.97275, 9.97289, 9.97303, 9.97317, 9.97331, 
   9.97345, 9.97358, 9.97371, 9.97384, 9.97396, 9.97409, 9.97421, 
   9.97433, 9.97445, 9.97456, 9.97468, 9.97479, 9.9749, 9.97501, 
   9.97511, 9.97522, 9.97532, 9.97542, 9.97552, 9.97562, 9.97571, 
   9.97581, 9.9759, 9.97599, 9.97608, 9.97617, 9.97626, 9.97634, 
   9.97643, 9.97651, 9.97659, 9.97667, 9.97675, 9.97682, 9.9769, 
   9.97697, 9.97705, 9.97712, 9.97719, 9.97726, 9.97733, 9.9774, 
   9.97746, 9.97753, 9.97759, 9.97765, 9.97772, 9.97778, 9.97784, 
   9.97789, 9.97795, 9.97801, 9.97806, 9.97812, 9.97817, 9.97823, 
   9.97828, 9.97833, 9.97838, 9.97843, 9.97848, 9.97853, 9.97857, 
   9.97862, 9.97867, 9.97871, 9.97875, 9.9788, 9.97884, 9.97888, 
   9.97892, 9.97896, 9.979, 9.97904, 9.97908, 9.97912, 9.97916, 
   9.97919, 9.97923, 9.97926, 9.9793, 9.97933, 9.97937, 9.9794, 
   9.97943, 9.97946, 9.9795, 9.97953, 9.97956, 9.97959, 9.97962, 
   9.97964, 9.97967, 9.9797, 9.97973, 9.97975, 9.97978, 9.97981, 
   9.97983, 9.97986, 9.97988, 9.97991, 9.97993, 9.97995, 9.97998, 
   9.98, 9.98002, 9.98004, 9.98007, 9.98009, 9.98011, 9.98013, 
   9.98015, 9.98017, 9.98019, 9.98021, 9.98023, 9.98025, 9.98026, 
   9.98028, 9.9803, 9.98032, 9.98033, 9.98035, 9.98037, 9.98038, 
   9.9804, 9.98041, 9.98043, 9.98044, 9.98046, 9.98047, 9.98049, 
   9.9805, 9.98052, 9.98053, 9.98054, 9.98056, 9.98057, 9.98058, 
   9.9806, 9.98061, 9.98062, 9.98063, 9.98064, 9.98065, 9.98067, 
   9.98068, 9.98069, 9.9807, 9.98071, 9.98072, 9.98073, 9.98074, 
   9.98075, 9.98076, 9.98077, 9.98078, 9.98079, 9.9808, 9.98081, 
   9.98082, 9.98082, 9.98083, 9.98084, 9.98085, 9.98086, 9.98086, 
   9.98087, 9.98088, 9.98089, 9.9809, 9.9809, 9.98091, 9.98092, 
   9.98092, 9.98093, 9.98094, 9.98094, 9.98095, 9.98096, 9.98096, 
   9.98097, 9.98098, 9.98098, 9.98099, 9.98099, 9.981, 9.981, 9.98101,
    9.98101, 9.98102, 9.98103, 9.98103, 9.98104, 9.98104, 9.98105, 
   9.98105, 9.98105, 9.98106, 9.98106, 9.98107, 9.98107, 9.98108, 
   9.98108, 9.98109, 9.98109, 9.98109, 9.9811, 9.9811, 9.98111, 
   9.98111, 9.98111, 9.98112, 9.98112, 9.98112, 9.98113, 9.98113, 
   9.98113, 9.98114, 9.98114, 9.98114, 9.98115, 9.98115, 9.98115, 
   9.98116, 9.98116, 9.98116, 9.98116, 9.98117, 9.98117, 9.98117, 
   9.98118, 9.98118, 9.98118, 9.98118, 9.98119, 9.98119, 9.98119, 
   9.98119, 9.98119, 9.9812, 9.9812, 9.9812, 9.9812, 9.98121, 9.98121,
    9.98121, 9.98121, 9.98121, 9.98122, 9.98122, 9.98122, 9.98122, 
   9.98122, 9.98123, 9.98123, 9.98123, 9.98123, 9.98123, 9.98123, 
   9.98124, 9.98124, 9.98124, 9.98124, 9.98124, 9.98124, 9.98124, 
   9.98125, 9.98125, 9.98125, 9.98125, 9.98125, 9.98125, 9.98125, 
   9.98126, 9.98126, 9.98126, 9.98126, 9.98126, 9.98126, 9.98126, 
   9.98126, 9.98126, 9.98127, 9.98127, 9.98127, 9.98127, 9.98127, 
   9.98127, 9.98127, 9.98127, 9.98127, 9.98127, 9.98128, 9.98128, 
   9.98128, 9.98128, 9.98128, 9.98128, 9.98128, 9.98128, 9.98128, 
   9.98128, 9.98128, 9.98128, 9.98129, 9.98129, 9.98129, 9.98129, 
   9.98129, 9.98129, 9.98129, 9.98129, 9.98129, 9.98129, 9.98129, 
   9.98129, 9.98129, 9.98129, 9.98129, 9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813,
    9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 
   9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 9.9813, 
   9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 
   9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 
   9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 
   9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 
   9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98131, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 
   9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 
   9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 
   9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 
   9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 
   9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 
   9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 
   9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 
   9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 
   9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98132, 
   9.98132, 9.98132, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 
   9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 
   9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 
   9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 
   9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 
   9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 
   9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 
   9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 
   9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 
   9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 
   9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 
   9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 
   9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133, 9.98133}}}
```

As you can see, the list is nested three times already.  Once I try to evaluate the following operation:

```
gndat = Table[
  Transpose[gthin (Exp[-tdat] - (1 - Exp[-τ])/τ)], {1}]
```

The output is now nested four times.

I tried to plot it using the following command:

```
ListPlot[gndat[[1]], Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}, 
 PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {0, 1000}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Zone", "Force"}]
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `Flatten` to remove extra brackets.

Comment: Is this not as simple as using Flatten?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Thank you very much!  I'm still learning to use Mathematica and actually realized that 'Flatten' is the answer shortly after posting this.  Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just

```
ListPlot[Flatten[data], Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}, 
 PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {0, 1000}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Zone", "Force"}]
```

[image]

EDIT: Oh like it was mentioned in the comments. :)

Comment: Correct answer, +1. New(-ish) to the site, I'd upvote you more if I could.